# Resolver does not work after upgrade to NG11

Tags: angular, typescript

I´ve made the following resolver:

```ts
export class OverviewResolver implements Resolve<ItemDto[]> {

    selectedItemStatus: number = 0;

    constructor(
        private readonly itemService: ItemsService
    ) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<ItemDto[]> {
        this.selectedItemStatus = +route.url[1].path;
        if (this.selectedItemStatus !== 8) {
            return this.itemService.getItemsByStatus(this.selectedItemStatus);
        } else {
            return this.itemService.getAllItems();
        }
    }
}
```

for this component:

```ts
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  currentItemlist: ItemDto[] | undefined;
  subscriptionItemlist: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptionItemlist = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data: { resolution: ItemDto[] }) => { <== here is the error
      this.currentItemlist = data.resolution;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (!!this.subscriptionItemlist) {
      this.subscriptionItemlist.unsubscribe();
    };
  }
}
```

and I get this error at position "(data: { resolution: ItemDto[] })"

```ts
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: PartialObserver<Data> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(data: {    resolution: ItemDto[];}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PartialObserver<Data> | undefined'.
      Property 'complete' is missing in type '(data: {    resolution: ItemDto[];}) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver<Data>'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: Data) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(data: {    resolution: ItemDto[];}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Data) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Property 'resolution' is missing in type 'Data' but required in type '{ resolution: ItemDto[]; }'.ts(2769)
types.d.ts(64, 5): 'complete' is declared here.
overview.component.ts(19, 77): 'resolution' is declared here.
```

I don´t know how to solve this, because the resolver for me worked fine under Angular 9.

Comment: your implments type in the resolve should be Resolve<{reolution: ItemDto[]}> and same for returned Observable<.....> or you can map resulting values to data.resolution instead

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of the cause either, but there may have been typing changes in v11 that cause this. You could always avoid declaring the type of the parameter in your subscription.

```
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {...})
```

Alternatively, for the benefit of using TypeScript, you can assert the type before subscribing:

```
this.activatedRoute.data
.pipe(map(data => data.resolution as ItemDto[]))
.subscribe((resolution: ItemDto[]) => {...})
```